# R - downloading a subset from original dataset

Tags: r, download, dataset, subset

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to download (from the website) a subset made from original dataset in Rdata format. The easiest way of course is to proceed in this manner:

```
set<-url("http://xxx.com/datasets/dataset.RData")
load(set)
subset<-set[set$var=="yyy",]
```

however I'm trying to speed up my code and avoid downloading unnecessary columns.

Thanks for any feedback.

Matt

Comment: You could set up a simple API on the server that could send a subset of data based upon `GET` parameters.

Comment: Good point, but the server isn't mine so I cannot do this. I was rather looking for some more sophisticated tools in R, but I have no idea if there is even a chance.

Comment: Well, you'd probably have to extend the code of `url()` and establish a hook that only accepts certain rows. If there's nothing in CRAN that does this, then you'll most likely have to roll your own.

Answer (score 4):

There is no mechanism for that task. There is also no mechanism for inspecting .Rdata files. In the past when this has been requested, people have been advised to convert to a real database management system.